# How to update a row in a Sql table

Tags: sql, groovy

How can I update a row in an SQL table instead adding an addition row. For example I have a table named `Machine` having columns `MachineName`, `ProgramName`, `RightCount`, `LeftCount`. In first row it has some values. I am fetching the value from a text file. In case if there is a change in RightCount. It has to update the same row instead adding a new row with all the same data. 
I tried and have groovy-sql code as: This inserts new row when there is any change in data. How can I achieve updating a single row instead adding new row.

```
def map = ["MachineName": e.getMachineName(),       
"ProgramName": e.getProgramName(),              
"RightCount":  e.getRightCount(),           
"LeftStentCount": e.getLeftCount()]

def stat = "Insert Into [try].[dbo].[Machine] (MachineName,ProgramName,RightCount, LeftCount) VALUES (:MachineName, :ProgramName:RightCount, :LeftCount)"

def result = sql.executeInsert(map, stat)
```

Comment: You should read about **UPDATE** sql command.

Comment: Not to be a jerk, but if you type your question into google.com the answer will come up many times.

Comment: http://groovy-lang.org/databases.html

Comment: @MikeW core of question has NOTHING to groovy

Comment: @JacekCz the question is tagged with groovy and a quick check of posters previous questions show it's all about groovy

Comment: What about `executeUpdate` as in the [link](http://groovy-lang.org/databases.html) which Mike W said

Comment: Yeah, this question is too simple. Just read the definition of a SQL UPDATE and you're good.

Comment: @MikeW Thank you.