# How to use Sql Insert and Update together?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert one row at the start into a table. In further I just need to update that row instead of adding an extra row. How can i do that. i read Sql update, but little lost. I am trying an example like, A column called FirstName always remain the same but the rest of the columns can change. But i cannot use SET columnName Firstname = ''. Because i wont know which FirstName i am going to read. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Consider reading about **upserts** for your specific RDBMS.

Comment: UPSERT or MERGE

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please post sample data and how it changes over time.

Comment: In what way is this different to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50063090/how-to-update-a-row-in-a-sql-table Is it to do with groovy? Please tag appropriately

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Nice link for the sample data, but 99 times out of 100, sample data is best served as ddl+dml. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) have a pretty nice text to ddl feature, I think you should probably consider linking to it next time.

Comment: @horse_with_no_name, i am using sql-server database

Comment: OK, that means you need to edit your question and add that tag. I'll do it for you, Note that this might be answered quicker if you included that tag 5 days ago. Further to this, if you are serious about an answer I suggest you post sample data as requested